# How to create platform-specific Python wheel with build tool?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

`build` (https://github.com/pypa/build) is a great tool to create wheels. However, I could not find a way to create platform-specific wheels that I can do with `python setup.py --plat-name=linux_x86_64`.

I have tried these approaches:

- Add `setup.cfg` with `[bdist_wheel] \ plat-name=linux_x86_64` content. It works well but I want to make this dynamic (on Windows, I want to use `win_amd64`).
- I tried `python -m build -w -n "--config-setting=--plat-name(=linux_x86_64)"`, no success.

Renaming the created `.whl` file feels a hacky solution.

What is the state-of-the-art way to resolve this?

Comment: Could you share your `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` as well?

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan In my case I only have a `pyproject.toml` without any `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` and the question remains. How is it possible to tell `python -m build` to set a certain platform?

Comment: @Woltan, you are right, I missed the case that config can also be a `.toml` file. So Tibor, if you use `pyproject.toml`, then please share it. I have a few ideas how can it be fixed, and I need the configuration to test locally.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan I think ANY `pyproject,toml` setup that lets `python -m build` set the correct file name would suffice.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/202 (maybe you have read this already).

Answer (score 3):

Creating a custom command class is not necessary. The syntax to provide `plat_name` explicitly is like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

def get_platname():
    # do whatever you need here
    return "potato"

setup(
    name="myproj",
    version="0.1",
    options={
        "bdist_wheel": {
            "plat_name": get_platname(),
        },
    },    
)
```

Answer (score 1):

### With `bdist_wheel` setuptools command

The solution I have applied is quite straightforward. Here are the relevant parts of the `setup.py`.

```py
from wheel.bdist_wheel import bdist_wheel

class BDistWheel(bdist_wheel):
    def get_tag(self) -> List[str]:
        return (self.python_tag, "none", "linux")


cmdclass = {
    "bdist_wheel": BDistWheel,
}

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass=cmdclass,
    ...
)
```

This creates a package with name `<name>-<version>-py3-none-linux.whl`. The `py3-none-linux` is generated from the returned tuple for the `get_tag` function. You can find more info in [PEP-427](https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#file-name-convention).

### With extension

The build system assumes that if the Python package is built with an extension, than it is platform-specific. This actually makes sense since a "pure" Python package is usually platform-independent. Here is a oversimplified solution to show how a built extension influences the tags:

```py
from setuptools import Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


class DummyExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("dummy.extension", sources=[])

class DummyExtensionBuild(build_ext):
    def run(self) -> None:
        return

cmdclass = {
    "build_ext": DummyExtensionBuild,
}

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass=cmdclass,
    ...
)
```

This creates a very specific wheel: `<name>-<version>-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl`.

Of course, you overwrite the tag by applying the first approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pure `pyproject.toml` setup the platform can be set via:

```
python -m build -w -C="--global-option=--plat-name" -C="--global-option=anything_you_like_here"
```

Kudos to @sinoroc in the comment above for sharing this link: https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/202

Answer (score 0):

As many as I tried to set the `plat-name` using `--config-setting`, it did not work.

> However, I could not find a way to create platform-specific wheels that I can do with `python setup.py --plat-name=linux_x86_64`.

You can read the `--plat-name` option in your `setup.py` and override the `bdist_wheel`.

```py
from setuptools import setup
from wheel.bdist_wheel import bdist_wheel

def get_plat_name():
    """Parses value of the --plat-name from the program arguments."""

class wheel(bdist_wheel):
    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        self.plat_name = get_plat_name()

setup(cmdclass={"bdist_wheel": wheel})
```

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/wheel/blame/main/README.rst#L13-L14 - wheel has no public API and is not intended to be imported.